# Get non-null columns in a SQL join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query that gets the data from two tables (TABLE_ONE left join TABLE_TWO) that have the same columns. I need to get the data from TABLE_ONE, but if the data is null and in TABLE_TWO it is not null, then the column of TABLE_TWO is returned.

TABLE_ONE

| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| car |  | red | 4 |
| bike |  | blue |  |

TABLE_TWO

| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| car | spain |  | 7 |
| bike |  | blue | 9 |

This is the query:

```
select distinct *
from TABLE_ONE T1
left join TABLE_TWO T2 on T1.data1 = T2.data1
  and (T1.data2 = T2.data2 OR (T1.data2 like '' OR T2.data2 like ''))
  and (T1.data3 = T2.data3 OR (T1.data3 like '' OR T2.data3 like ''))
```

This is what I get:

| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| car |  | red | 4 | car | spain | red | 7 |
| bike |  | blue |  | bike |  | blue | 9 |

This is what I need:

| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| car | spain | red | 4 |
| bike |  | blue | 9 |

Is it possible to merge the columns that have the same name?, that is, a different column, but that are not null, if both columns are null, take the one from TABLE_ONE

Comment: Your sample data shows no nulls

Comment: Note that your join may very well find multiple matching table 2 columns, which will result in multiple result rows

Answer (score 0):

Use *coalesce*

```
Select
  coalesce(t1.data1, t2.data1) Data1,
  coalesce(t1.data2, t2.data2) Data2,
  coalesce(t1.data3, t2.data3) Data3,
  coalesce(t1.data4, t2.data4) Data4
From...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a full outer join here.  MySQL does not directly support them, but we can emulate them via a union query:

```sql
SELECT t1.data1,
       COALESCE(t1.data2, t2.data2) AS data2,
       COALESCE(t1.data3, t2.data3) AS data3,
       COALESCE(t1.data4, t2.data4) AS data4
FROM TABLE_ONE t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_TWO t2 ON t2.data1 = t1.data1
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.data1, t2.data2, t2.data3, t2.data4
FROM TABLE_ONE t1
RIGHT JOIN TABLE_TWO t2 ON t2.data1 = t1.data1
WHERE t1.data1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: Don't think they are asking for a full outer join?

Comment: That depends on the definition of `don't`.

Comment: I understand the coalesce function, but it only checks that it is not null, in this case the data is an empty string '', that is where I have the problem, I don't know if there is any way for coalesce to check that or some other function